# TextBox: не удаётся обновить свойство Text из обработчика события, вызываемого по таймеру

Tags: c#, многопоточность, события, таймер, textbox

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал изучать C#. До этого работал в Delphi и в Qt (C++). Во время тренировки столкнулся с большой проблемой, которая может показаться очень глупой.

Это очень длинная история, я постараюсь описать всё кратко и точно.
Рассматриваем три объекта: 1) **TextBox**; 2) **МойКласс** с таймером внутри; 3) **форму** главного окна, которая их инкапсулирует.

**МойКласс** запускает таймер, который генерирует событие **UpdateDuration** с интервалом примерно два раза в секунду.

```
// Обработчик события таймера
private void TickerCheck(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Animation) { Invalidate(); }
    if (Field.GameIsRunning) {
        if (Updater == TimerUpdateTicks) {

            Updater = 0;
            GameDuration = Field.RunningGameDuration;
            OnUpdateDuration();
        }
        ++Updater;
    }
}
// внутренний обработчик события UpdateDuration
protected void OnUpdateDuration()
{
    UpdateDurationEventArgs ud = new UpdateDurationEventArgs();
    EventHandler<UpdateDurationEventArgs> h = UpdateDuration;
    if (h != null) {
        ud.Duration = GameDuration;
        h(this, ud);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Посылка отправлена: " + ud.Duration.ToString());
}
```

Подписанты события **UpdateDuration** получают аргумент, содержащий внутри **TimeSpan**

```
public class UpdateDurationEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private TimeSpan duration;
    public UpdateDurationEventArgs() { duration = TimeSpan.Zero; }
    public TimeSpan Duration {
        get { return duration; }
        set { duration = value; }
    }
}
```

Я собирался использовать этот TimeSpan для обновления текста в TextBox. Этот TextBox выглядит вот так: [image: Текстбокс] Думаю, вам уже понятно, что я хочу сделать :) В нём должно обновляться текущее время игры. Для пользователя он играет роль секундомера.

Подписантом события **UpdateDuration** является **форма** главного окна. Она принимает событие и должна (по задумке) обновлять текст внутри **TextBox**

```
void UpdateTimer(object sender, UpdateDurationEventArgs ud)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Посылка получена: " + ud.Duration.ToString());
    uint t_Seconds = (uint)ud.Duration.TotalSeconds,
         t_Minutes = t_Seconds/60,
         t_Hours   = t_Minutes/60;

    t_Seconds = t_Seconds%60;
    t_Minutes = t_Minutes%60;
    t_Hours   = t_Hours  %100;

    string newText = t_Hours.ToString("D2") + ':' + t_Minutes.ToString("D2") + ':' + t_Seconds.ToString("D2");
    textBox_timer.Text = newText; // вот здесь она должна обновлять его
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Посылка распакована: " + ud.Duration.ToString());
}
```

Но! Не тут-то было. Кто-нибудь уже видит ошибку? Нет? Я не вижу :Т
Когда я запускал таймер, **TextBox** всегда оставался в нулях. Тогда я создал кнопку и попробовал запустить обработчик события вручную:

```
void Button_Rec_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDurationEventArgs ud = new UpdateDurationEventArgs();
    ud.Duration = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new System.Random().Next(8000));
    UpdateTimer(this, ud);
}
```

И вот, по кнопке всё прекрасно работает: в TextBox рандомно выставляется разное время. До этого я ещё не пробовал ловить исключения в C#. Порылся в MSDN и сделал так:

```
void UpdateTimer(object sender, UpdateDurationEventArgs ud)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Посылка получена: " + ud.Duration.ToString());
    uint t_Seconds = (uint)ud.Duration.TotalSeconds,
         t_Minutes = t_Seconds/60,
         t_Hours   = t_Minutes/60;

    t_Seconds = t_Seconds%60;
    t_Minutes = t_Minutes%60;
    t_Hours   = t_Hours  %100;

    string newText = t_Hours.ToString("D2") + ':' + t_Minutes.ToString("D2") + ':' + t_Seconds.ToString("D2");
    try { // добавил блок try catch
        textBox_timer.ResetText();          // и подставил строчки для дебага
                                      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("           resetText"); 
        textBox_timer.Text = newText;
                                      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("           newText");
    } catch (System.Exception) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Звездец, граждане!");
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Посылка распакована: " + ud.Duration.ToString());
}
```

Что же я увидел?

[image: Звездец, граждане!]

<strike>Звездец</strike> Фрустрацию в чистом виде. Посылка отправляется (генерируется событие, см. код **OnUpdateDuration**), принимается подписантом, но выбрасывается исключение, причём *даже* при *ресете текста*. При этом, по той же кнопке, вручную, всё прекрасно работает:

[image: Прекрасно работает]

Вы уже видите ошибку? Что я сделал не так? :Т
Я закликал эту бедную кнопку до смерти (более 10 кликов в секунду), но "звездец" в консоль так и не вывелся - обработка прекрасно проходит.

Тут вы вправе предположить, что **МойКласс** отправляет какой-то инвалидный TimeSpan. Смею заверить, что это совсем не так: по тому же таймеру, в дебажную консоль обработчик выводит время без проблем:

[image: Замечательно работает]

Интересный момент: я сделал так, чтобы при ручной остановке таймера **МойКласс** отправлял событие **UpdateDuration** ещё один раз, уже после остановки таймера, чтобы передать подписантам нулевой **TimeSpan.Zero**. Так я намеревался сбрасывать время на TextBox. Так вот, это завершающее событие принимается тоже безо всяких проблем.

[image: И почему так происходит?]

Забавно, но если заменить текстбокс на лейбл, ситуация не меняется. И только если использовать *таймер, напрямую принадлежащий* **форме**, всё хорошо работает. Но разве таймер, работающий в другом классе, нарушает какие-то принципы ООП? Ведь объекты **МойКласс**, **форма** и **TextBox** находятся все в одном главном потоке! Я в недоумении.

Программа делает то, что написал программист, а не то что он хотел. Где же у меня ошибка? Я угробил вчера несколько часов на поиски решения, до рези в глазах. Даже мютекс в обработчик ставил, хотя он тут вроде и ни к чему. Помогите, пожалуйста.

WindowsXP, NetFramework 4, среда SharpDevelop.
*Вы заработали достижение! Вы прочитали мой вопрос полностью! Спасибо :)*

Comment: Я не дочитал вопрос, но вангую, что вы обращаетесь к UI-контролам из побочного потока, в котором приходят сообщения от таймера.

Comment: И да, WPF или WinForms?

Comment: @VladD
Честно сказать, не знаю) Вроде в WPF используется XAML, а я его не использую. И если так, то выходит что это WinForms

Comment: Денис, Вы молодец! Ваш вопрос - пример того, как человек пытается разобраться в проблеме сам, прикладывает для этого значительные усилия, и задает вопрос, который включает описание этих попыток. На такие вопросы хочется отвечать! Думаю, @VladD со мной согласится.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. Писать этот вопрос было тоже приятно, я прямо-таки высказался о наболевшем) Учту это в будущем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не написали, каким именно из многочисленных таймеров, доступных в .NET и его фреймворках, вы пользуетесь. Некоторые из них доставляют сообщения в UI-потоке, некоторые — в фоновом потоке. (А некоторые по-разному, в зависимости от того, как вы их отконфигурировали.)

Судя по всему, вы выбрали таймер, который доставляет сообщения в фоновом потоке. При этом попытка обратиться к контролам из кода таймера приводит к исключению: из фоновых потоков работать с контролами **нельзя**.

Какие есть пути решения?

1. Возьмите подходящий таймер. Например, если вы пишете Winforms-приложение, подойдёт [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Если по каким-то очень уважительным причинам вы не можете воспользоваться подходящим таймером («ну типа я попробовал, но чёта не работает кароч» не считается уважительной причиной), то вам придётся смаршаллировать вызов в UI-поток. Для Winforms это делается так:

   ```
   if (textBox_timer.InvokeRequired)
   {
       textBox_timer.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { textBox_timer.Text = что-то; }));
   }
   else
   {
       textBox_timer.Text = что-то;
   }
   ```

Comment: Да, точно! Совсем забыл. Верно, я использовал таймер из System.Timers. А таймер, который "нормально работает" был из System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Значит, когда наступает момент вызова события, таймер из фонового потока обращается к МоемуКлассу и его обработчик выполняется из цикла обработки событий фонового потока?

Comment: @Денис: Таймер запускает event в фоновом потоке. Поскольку ваш класс подписан на этот event, он его и получает. В том потоке, в котором этот event запускается.

Comment: [Вот это да!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ7JV.png) Да тут теперь **всё** работает! Спасибо большое! Даже не знаю что бы без вас делал)
Пойду теперь изучать маршаллирование

Comment: @Денис: Пожалуйста! Рад, что всё получилось!

Comment: прошу прощения, читаю MSDN и стало интересно.
В методе Invoke вы объявляете делегат MethodInvoker через лямбда-выражение. В MSDN приведён пример:
`this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { ... })`
Вы использовали лямбда выражение:
`this.invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ( ... )))`
Пустые скобки перед лямбда-оператором обозначают void, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Денис, пустые скобки означают отсутствие параметров

Comment: @Андрей Благодарю! Теперь изучаю лямбда-выражения xD какой же классный этот NET

Comment: Попробовал теперь и с маршаллированием, и с лямбда-выражением, и всё суперски работает :D И через Invoke мне нравится гораздо больше, потому что от более точного таймера. Спасибо

Comment: @Денис: Вот и отлично!