# Доступ к элементу, не из того потока в котором он был создан

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть код

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    server = new ServerObject(listBox2, listBox1);
    listenThread = new Thread(server.Listen);
    listenThread.Start();
}
```

В классе ServerObject

```
public void Listen()
{
    Action action = () => ListBoxMsg.Items.Add("Сервер запущен");
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action);
    else
        ListBoxMsg.Items.Add("Сервер запущен");

   ............
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку ошибка Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'listBox2' не из того потока, в котором он был создан.

Comment: UI у вас на чем? WinForms? WPF? или еще что-нибудь? Добавьте метку. Ну и да, все верно, обращаться из другого потока к элементам UI нельзя, нужен маршалинг, например как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630415/198316)

Comment: Я понимаю что нельзя, именно по этой причине я использовал Invoke. Но все равно вылетает ошибка

Comment: Как именно объявлен ServerObject? Это визуальный компонент? Вы же проверяете его свойство InvokeRequired, а не ListBoxMsg.InvokeRequired - а они могут выдавать разный результат. Например, ServerObject.InvokeRequired будет выдавать false даже из стороннего потока, если ServerObject не был реально размещен на форме или показан пользователю

Comment: ServerObject.Invoke, соответственно, тоже вызывает код в том потоке, в котором было создано окно/хэндл для ServerObject (которе у вас создано не было). Используйте ListBoxMsg.InvokeRequired/Invoke - должно помочь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, ServerObject у вас унаследован от Control. Для Control-ов, которые не были отображены (чей handle еще не был создан), `InvokeRequired` возвращает `false`.

Вместо проверки `ServerObject.InvokeRequired` вам нужно проверять `ListBoxMsg.InvokeRequired` и вызывать `ListBoxMsg.Invoke`. Или просто вызывать `ListBoxMsg.Invoke`, если вы заранее знаете что выполнение происходит в фоновом потоке:

```
public void Listen()
{
    Action action = () => ListBoxMsg.Items.Add("Сервер запущен");
    if (ListBoxMsg.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ListBoxMsg.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
   ............
 }
```

или

```
public void Listen()
{
    ListBoxMsg.Invoke(() => ListBoxMsg.Items.Add("Сервер запущен"));
   ............
}
```